# Bootstrap is overriding custom CSS in Ruby on Rails 4 website?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I used http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/integrating-rails-and-bootstrap-part-1 to install Bootstrap on my Rails 4 website.
Basically, I installed the gems:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
```

And then in my application.css.scss I have:

```
 ...* defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is 
 generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

/*some css code that does work.*/
```

It's working perfectly, aside from one snag. In my css file for my

```
/* 
Filters
*/
#filters{
    position: relative;
}

.searchbox{
    width:100px;
}

.filter{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and then in my view, I have

```
<div id="filters">
    <input type="text" class="form-control filter"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control filter"/>
</div>
```

However, the inputs are not displayed side by side. If I remove form-control in the inputs class, it does work. I checked in chrome, and basically the filter class's display:inline-block was being crossed out by the bootstrap form-control.

I'm not very good at css, but as far as I can tell, rails is putting bootstrap's css file after mine, which is causing bootstrap to be more "important".

I looked and looked, but I couldn't find a way to have my css loaded AFTER the bootstrap css (if I'm even right over the source of this confusion)

Hope you can help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In css, rules that appear later in the same stylesheet or in a different stylesheet which loads later in the html will override similar ones already defined. For example

```
p { color: blue; }

p { color: red; }
```

will produce red text.

Your `@import` statements for bootstrap are referenced by the `require_self` line which appears after the `require_tree .` line. As a result, the bootstrap css will appear at the end of your compiled stylesheet and override any rules with the same selectors.

With sass, you are recommended not to use sprockets as you can't really control the source order but rather use `@import` for each of your sass partial files.

Reversing the two require lines might work well enough for you. Otherwise I would suggest you remove all the sprockets directives and comments above your `@import`s, move any code below into its own partial and explicitly @import each partial in the exact order you want.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your custom CSS in linked to from your HTML after the bootstrap links.

```
HTML head
link bootstrap
link custom CSS
```

Comment: Ya, as I said, it's showing as crossed out by chrome, it's loading it before bootstrap (which is the problem).

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/bounty-dd7086d179805593da1e8b39d3c4a1fb.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-aca441a413229261d1fac1928a6bfdb8.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />

Comment: Can you link your header file with the links to your CSS in it. Just update post. I am much better at giving help when I can visualize it :)

Comment: Header file? What do you mean?

Comment: I'm thinking of the <head> in your html. But you said that it already listed bootstrap first and custom css after so nvm.

Answer (score 0):

First:
Follow [Bootstrap `application.css.scss` order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26002918/1608670).

Second:
Run these command in console in order:
`rake assets:clobber` (Remove all compiled assets)
`RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile`

Third:
Restart server with production mode.